# Code into function with parameters

Tags: jquery

I have a code

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".class1").each(function() {
    jQuery(".class2").hide("fast");
    jQuery(this).children("input").click(
      function() {
        if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('class3')) {
          jQuery(".class2").toggle("slow");
        } else {
          jQuery(".class2").hide("slow");
        }
      });
  });
});
```

How I can change it into a reusable function with parameters class1, class2, class3 to many usage ?

Comment: Do you need to learn how to make a function? I don't get it

Comment: Just make a function and pass the three _class_ as parameters.

Comment: I've tried do something to use this code like a function: inputshow('class1','class2','class3')  , where 'class1' etc. would be a real class for example, and code above use in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function where you make the class names parameters like so:

```
var exampleFunction = function(class1, class2, class3) {
  jQuery(class1).each(function() {
    jQuery(class2).hide("fast");
    jQuery(this).children("input").click(
      function() {
        if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass(class3)) {
          jQuery(class2).toggle("slow");
        } else {
          jQuery(class2).hide("slow");
        }
      });
  });
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
exampleFunction('.class1','.class2','class3');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply wrap your relevant code in a function like the below `doSomething` function, then from your wherever you want to call your function, you can do the following:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var class1 = jQuery(".class1"),
        class2 = jQuery(".class2"),
        class3 = "class3";

    // Reusable function doSomething
    doSomething(class1, class2, class3name);
});

function doSomething(class1, class2, class3name){
    class1.each(function() {
    class2.hide("fast");
    jQuery(this).children("input").click(
      function() {
        if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass(class3)) {
          class2.toggle(slow);
        } else {
          class2.hide("slow");
        }
      });
  });
}
```

I used `var` in order to give the classes more meaning, however if you wanted something shorter you can call the function like so:

```
doSomething(jQuery(".class1"), jQuery(".class2"), "class3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".' + class1 + '").each(
    function() {
    jQuery(".' + Class1 + '").hide("fast");
        jQuery(this).children("input").click(
            function(){
                if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('class3')) {
                    jQuery(".' + Class2 +'").toggle("slow");
                } else {
                    jQuery(".' + Class2 +'").hide("slow");
                }
            });
    });
});
```